# Hey guys i was trying read csv file using pandas in pycharm i am getting this error how to resolve it ,i was able to run in googlecolab but in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

#i am getting url error how do i resolve it

```
  C:\Python\python.exe E:/data_science/Python_basic/module1_eda/EDA.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1350, in do_open
        encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 972, in send
        self.connect()
      File "C:\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1447, in connect
        server_hostname=server_hostname)
      File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
        session=session
      File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
        self.do_handshake()
      File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/data_science/Python_basic/module1_eda/EDA.py", line 9, in <module>
        adult = pd.read_csv(data_url,names=column_headers)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
        return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
        parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
        self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
        return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
        self._open_handles(src, kwds)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 229, in _open_handles
        errors=kwds.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 614, in get_handle
        storage_options=storage_options,
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 312, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
        with urlopen(req_info) as req:
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 212, in urlopen
        return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1393, in https_open
        context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
      File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1352, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)>
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to download the datafile from some URL and because of self-signed certificate you're getting this error. You can simply disable SSL verification during fetching.

```py
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```